# Multilanguage Next.js app with different language builds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multilingual, next.js

I would like to build a Next.js website and it should be multilanguage. 
Each language is going to have its own domain, so there is no need to implement instant language switcher.
It's going to work the next way: 
1) user goes to the website.com, the js code detects user location/language etc
2) it redirects to the website with detected language.

So I am going to have one client app, but it should have different languages for different domains.

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Even with this redirect logic I would use https://www.i18next.com/ and https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector if you detect the language and then redirect the languageDetector will then do the same and set the corresponding local or instead of languageDetector you just detect the domain and use this to set the local. If you really need the redirect logic  I hope you detect the language and redirect from server side and not with js.